# job in cron under unix server

Tags: cron

I need to schedule a **cronjob** under UNIX server, which will fulfill the below requirement.

in this i need to login to the server with my username and i have to check the status of my application. i am getting the output whenever I execute the script in mount point.

For the above scenario I need to set a **cronjob** on daily basis so that everyday I will get the  mail with the output that is appearing.

Comment: So the cron cob should mail you an update with the log from the already running application? (and then rotate the log?)

Answer (score 1):

Your execution file which send the output via email is like below.

```
30 8 * * * /your/execution/file/location 2>&1 | mail -s "sending cron output" example@mail.example
```

This will execute the script daily 8:30 am and send email.

Comment: You don’t need to use `mail`, `cron` can email a job’s output on its own.

Comment: How does this "check the status of the application"? To me it sounds like he's having a long-running program and that he wants the occasional mail with a log from it.